# Sum sign operation

Tags: summation

I want to solve for $T$.

$$21 + \sum_{t=1}^T x^t = \sum_{t=0}^{T} 4x^t$$

I do not really know how to calculate with the Sum signs.

Comment: Use dollar sign at the beginning and at the end of a formula to sate a formula. Then use LaTeX syntax.

Comment: For basic MathJax tutorial see [this post on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/250955)

Comment: There are no solutions if $x=\pm1$. What are the other restrictions on $x$?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean
$$21+\sum_{t=1}^{T}x^t=\sum_{t=0}^{T}4x^t$$

As $4$ in the right hand sum is a constant we can extract it from the sum:

$$21+\sum_{t=1}^{T}x^t=4\sum_{t=0}^{T}x^t$$

If we assume $x\neq0$, we can absorb the $1$ into the sum: 
$$20 + 1 + \sum_{t=1}^{T}x^t=20+\sum_{t=0}^{T}x^t$$

$$20+\sum_{t=0}^{T}x^t=4\sum_{t=0}^{T}x^t$$

As we have 4 times the sum on the right hand side we can simply subtract it on both sides.

$$20=3\sum_{t=0}^{T}x^t$$

We now apply the formula for the geometric sum.

$$\frac{20}{3}=\frac{1-x^{T+1}}{1-x}=\frac{x^{T+1}-1}{x-1}$$

If you dont have any informations about $x$ you need to play around with combinations of $x$ and $T$ to get the solution to your problem. If you need to find $T$ as a function of $x$, you will need to solve for $T$.

$$\frac{20}{3}(x-1)+1=x^{T+1}$$
$$\ln[\frac{20}{3}(x-1)+1]=(T+1)\ln(x)$$
$$T=\frac{\ln[\frac{20}{3}(x-1)+1]}{\ln(x)}-1$$

But this formula only makes sense if $T \in N$

Comment: It's worth noting that you can continue this a bit to get $3x^{T+1}-20x+17=0$ as long as $x\ne 1$, so for $T=1$ we have the solutions $x=(10\pm\sqrt{83})/3$ and for $T=2$ we have $x=(-3\pm\sqrt{213})/6$.

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the right side by 4 and then shift the $t$s.

Also, this is a geometric sequence. The formula for a geometric sequence is $$\sum ^T _{t=1} x^t =x\frac{1-x^T}{1-x}$$. Just plug in the formula and solve.